# Final decision made, retirement begins Friday

Tags: discussion

In the spirit of the high holy day of Christianity, it's time for (metaphorical) death and renewal.

I came back because of the twitstorm and felt I could help out, but it's clear I have other venues.  What this place has taught me is that I have something to say.  I'm grateful for that, but I've also learned that this is not the place to say it.  100K is a respectable run.  I think at this point, I've said my piece.

Comment: In the spirit of "exit interviews", is there any comment on what has finally inspired this decision?

Comment: @Richard nah, it would just fall on deaf ears.

Comment: You will be missed, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goodbye and good luck once again.

Comment: Thanks, again, good luck to you and your family.  You sir, will be in my thoughts and prayers.  If you don't want my prayers, then you'll still be in my thoughts.  Good luck to you sir, and all the best.